# Unable to add the [classical-electrodynamics] tag

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonyms

[Resource reference for Induction due to Time Varying Magnetic Fields (TVMF)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573921/)

I asked this question 5 minutes before posting it here. I have tried to add the tag [classical-electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-electrodynamics) but it just shows in the edit menu like this:

---

[image]

And upon clicking save edits:

[image]

---

Which basically means there were no edits but neither there was an error shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classical-electrodynamics tag is a synonym of electromagnetism, see [its synonym page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/electromagnetism/synonyms).

Comment: It seemed to me that my question got reactivated doing so...Can you test (I do not have direct edit privileges)

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "reactivated" nor what you want me to test. Trying to add a tag to a question that already has its synonym on it just does nothing upon trying to say the edit.

Comment: I mean, when you edit a question which is years or even a few days old, the status of that question becomes *Active* and it appears on our primary home page

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi You can see the edit history of your question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/573921/revisions), there is no edit for your attempt to tag this question. You're likely confusing this with Qmechanic's edit at around the same time that *did* certainly bump the question.